# Why are page titles on some websites clickable URLs?

Tags: usability, standards

Why on sites like Stack Overflow, Techcrunch, Smashing Magazine, etc. are the page titles (i.e. the text at the top of the page) clickable URLs that redirect to the same page that the user is on?

Some examples:

[image]

I believe that this does not effect SEO as search engines ignore internal links.

Is it for usability purposes?

Comment: Visually you can't tell they are, unless you notice when you mouse over it. Plus on most sites they are not. That's why I am trying to determine the pros and cons of it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

More than anything, it provides a link to the **default state** of the page.

For example, for this very stack overflow page it is a user can get here through any of the following non-default links:

- [Why are Page Titles on some websites (including Stack Overflow) Clickable URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904381/)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904381#foobar
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904381?sort=date

While the default link is actually:

- [Why are Page Titles on some websites (including Stack Overflow) Clickable URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904381/why-are-page-titles-on-some-websites-including-stack-overflow-clickable-urls)

If users are unable to get to the default state, they end up bookmarking or emailing the non-default link which propagates to new users and the problem just multiplies.

Clicking on the title link of the post will restore the default state and strip off any query parameters (?sort=date), named anchors (#foobar) and fix the story slug (/why-are-page-titles/...).

Answer (score 25):

It allows you to right-click on it and choose *Copy link location* (or equivalent) so that you can easily paste it in an email for example. This requires less time than copying it from the location bar, and some people run their browser without a visible location bar to save previous screen space.

Comment: Better yet, you can select and copy the title itself, link intact, into many email programs...

Comment: You also have the canonical URL to the question even if the current document’s URL references a particular answer. See for example the URL of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904381/why-are-stack-overflow-page-titles-clickable-urls/904386#904386

Comment: If you want to give people a function to copy link location, why don't you make it verbose like youtube?

Comment: Because it will clutter the page, while the link takes no space.

Answer (score 8):

I use it to refresh the page (yes, I could press F5 too).

Comment: same here, F5 triggers post data to be sent a second time on some sites, so out of habit I tend to not use it on pages with forms

Comment: This is why you (the site developper) are supposed to redirect a POST request after handling it, so that a subsequent reload will properly do a GET instead. Unfortunately, as you wrote, many sites don't get it right.

Comment: @Thomas Same here for the same reason.

Answer (score 6):

The URL redirects to the beginning of the page, in case you arrived on the page via a specific answer (all answers are also clickable URLs). This way, you get the URL of the question, not of an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes Jakob Nielsen has stated that linking to yourself is a [web design mistake](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20031222.html) (nr 10). And I agree.

More reading info [here. (nr 10)](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20031110.html)

Comment: I agree with his comments - it can be confusing for the user

Comment: so linking to "yourself" with named anchors/bookmarks is also considered a design mistake?

Comment: Nielsen suggests it's a mistake when the links do nothing as they may confuse users. If the links provide some affordance, such as making it easier to bookmark and share, it is true that they serve _some_ purpose—though it may not immediately be perceptible to the user.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is why they did it, but I find it useful to siphon off tabs:

If I look at something briefly and think "I'd like to read this thoroughly in a minute but continue with what I was doing before", I can do this:

I can right click the link, click "open in a new tab" and then click "back" and continue nicely.

Comment: Or simply middle-click on the title and back, if your pointing device has that ability. Even faster :)

Comment: Good point!

My fancy mouse seems to do everything but middle click so I forget it exists for other people!

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [Permalink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permalink)... The name implies what it is, a permanent link.

It's the same reason that each answer on SO has a link you can copy.

Answer (score 0):

UX-wise clickable titles which don't bring the user anywhere may seem unusable though that leads us into the realm of [Affordance Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance) and whether or not the affordance is perceptible to users.

For example, clickable page titles may provide:

- A simple method for bookmarking a page to the desktop from a browser window.
- A context menu with additional choices allowing users to share a blog post or article.
- A method for updating the location bar so it's pointing at the canonical URL of the page.

For the sites you mentioned, however, it seems more likely the page titles were turned into hyperlinks using absolute URLs so analytics tooling could pick up inbound link clicks – those sending the referer info – resulting in  [DCMA takedown notices](https://writing.kemitchell.com/2018/09/02/Killjoy-DMCA.html) when people copied work and didn't update the URLs.

You'd be surprised what people do when they're being incentivized to produce work contractually.

Answer (score -1):

I think it inherits the behavior from CMS where each question is a node, which has 0<= answered question. Now think you go for a search on apache questions.
The result are displayed one after another.
In terms of CMS this is called a teaser. You get a full page with lots of questions where the question's title link to the full article(question + answers)

Its not a must, but you'll find it on most sites which uses a CMS.

Comment: Some sites that have this feature (including Stack Overflow) are bespoke and not CMS's

Answer (score -1):

As long as it does not harm anyone why would people be against it?

I prefer to have those links available as hitting refresh would reload all elements of the page instead of just following the direct link (to the same page) that uses cached elements.

Answer (score -1):

Makes sense to me, I find it useful! I have a lot of tabs open so I just right click the link and go back.

To me this makes perfect sense, from a SEO view this is also good! It forces it to read the page because it's linked.

Comment: I don't think self-linking has any effect on SEO, and certainly no positive effect.

Comment: Agreed - no effect to SEO because search engines ignore any internal links

Comment: Oh really? I must be getting confused.

Must be how CMS's use breadcrumbs.